# Canvas color gets saturated depending on the canvas width

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to draw an waveform on canvas elements created programmatically and all of them has the same fill properties, but when they show up in the browser (currently i'm testing on Chrome) the color of the last ones get more saturated than the others, like this:
[Take a look at the final of the waveform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPbCR.png)

I have tested varying the canvas width and this only happens on canvases bigger than 513px.

The function that I used to draw in the canvas:

```
drawWaveform (context, upperValues, lowerValues) {
context.strokeStyle = '#f00';
context.fillStyle = '#f00';
context.beginPath();

lowerValues
  .forEach((val, x) => {
    context.lineTo(
      x + 0.5,
      this.interpolateHeight(context.canvas.height, val) + 0.5);
  });

upperValues.reverse()
  .forEach((val, x) => {
    context.lineTo(
      (context.canvas.width - x) + 0.5,
      this.interpolateHeight(context.canvas.height, val) + 0.5
    );
  });

context.closePath();
context.stroke();
context.fill();
}
```

Before draw I call a function to clear the canvas:

```
clearCanvas (context) {
context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
}
```

I'd like to know how to make all canvases have the same color and why is this happening

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the actual data... Can you reproduce on [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ffogtpcq/)? Can you reproduce on an other browser/computer?

Comment: I would say that at the point where the colour becomes darker is where there is a zero and the paths overlap. The overlap causing the fill to get confused Try subtracting -0.5 from the upper val y coords (or ensure that the low and upper values do not cross). That may fix the problem.